# Why is my audio device switching?

Tags: sound, headphones

My computer keeps switching the audio device from "headphones" to "speakers", even though the headphones aren't plugged in. I rebooted the computer but the problem kept happening even while the computer was rebooting. It causes the speakers to make an annoying clicking noise whenever it switches from "headphones" to "speakers", and vice versa. It happens in bursts where it will switch multiple times in a small period of time, then wait a bit before starting up again. I've tried to plug a pair of headphones in to stop the problem but that did no good. Can some one help me out here?
-Seribro Sorrens

Comment: Why would they switch from headphones to speaker IF headphones were plugged in?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1176562/21005

Answer (score 1):

I have no information on what is causing your sound device continuously switching between headphones and speakers but there is a way to prevent it. If you use this method you will have to manually switch sound device between headphones and speakers when you need them.

To override automatic sound device switching:

- edit the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- find the line `load-module module-switch-on-port-available`
- insert a `#` at the beginning of the line to disable automatic port switching
- save the file and reboot.