# How can I change PulseAudio port priorities?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I list sources and sinks as follows:

```
pactl list sources
pactl list sinks
```

The output I get is:

```
...
    Ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority: 8900)
        analog-input-headphone-mic: Microphone (priority: 8700)
        analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (priority: 8800)
...
    Ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, available)
```

How do I change the priorities listed above and have them fixed at what I change them to? Note that I am not looking to set a default source and sink or to delete unwanted sources or sinks, I just want to be able to assign them different priorities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, use the following command to see the list of cards and ports:

```
pactl list sinks
```

Then, run (change out the filename to correspond to the port you want to modify (list the files in the `paths/` folder to see which ones there are)):

```
sudo vim /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf
```

to modify the priority (that value is multiplied by 100).

Comment: If you're using PipeWire the PulseAudio configuration files are stored in: `/usr/share/alsa-card-profile/mixer/paths/`

Comment: System specific configs can be found in `/etc/pulse/` and probably those should be modified to override values in /usr/share/ that will be stepped on during upgrades.

Comment: OK, but if this priority even lowest-first or highest-first? Ungooglable.

Comment: @alamar Priority is highest first. This can be verified by the output of the command `pactl list sinks`. The priority of your choice should be higher than the other ports. If needed you need to reduce the priority of the other ports by editing other files in the same directory. However, modifying `/etc/pulse/default.pa` is preferred to preserve the settings across upgrades.

Comment: @user10489 A good answer for modifying  `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (preferred to preserve the settings across upgrades) is at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182294/11169

Comment: @amitkumar the default port or sink might change if you use r.g. bluetooth for a while,  please see this [issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/870). How can you prevent that?

Comment: Sinks also have priorities, but the files are for ports. Can you set priorities for sinks, too?

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable some obscure setting in the UI (?) in order to actually automatically switch between ports, HDMI vs. internal audio in my case. Without the setting, it won't switch the ports regardless of their priorities.

Perhaps it is `module-switch-on-connect`

I think the following answer is relevant: https://askubuntu.com/a/158250/480388

Comment: I wonder if it was `module-udev-detect`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the setting you enabled?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find it yet, I will try to re-discover it.

Comment: I commented out `load-module module-switch-on-connect` and `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, Then ran `pulseaudio -k` and auto-switching to undesired sink on new audio device connect stopped .