# Completely disable PS4 controller's audio devices?

Tags: 18.04, sound, gamepad

It's annoying to always have to change my default audio device back to my headphones every time I plug my PS4 controllers in. Is there a way to completely disable them from ever being used as audio devices? Or at least not have them set themselves to default?

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154586/how-can-i-change-pulseaudio-port-priorities

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pavucontrol` tool. One silly thing I missed when I was attempting this: there are more tabs for the tool than are visible at one time; use the arrow buttons next to the tab handles to see more of them!

With the controller plugged in, find the Configuration tab, and find the controller device in the list. Mine says "DualShock 4 [CUH-ZCT2x]". Select Profile: Off.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not permanent

Comment: @RichieHH No? For me it has lasted past several reboots and unplugging/plugging the controller.

Comment: Works well for me, I'm also using the Flatpak of pavucontrol.