# Setting audio output priority in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, hdmi, headphones, output

I want to achieve the following behavior for my audio outputs:

1. if *HDMI is connected use it as audio output device*
2. else if *headphones are connected use them as output device*
3. else *use built-in speakers*

I already used this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1207638/664571 to set HDMI as default audio output on system boot. Now I have the problem that whenever headphones are connected the audio output switches to them. **So, headphones have higher priority than HDMI.**

Is there any way to change the priority in the described way?

Comment: Is this working in 20.04? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154586/how-can-i-change-pulseaudio-port-priorities

Comment: @nobody yes, thank you! I changed the priorities in my preferred way and it works fine. (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)