# Headphones selected as sound output device but sound comes from monitor

Tags: sound, headphones, monitor, settings, pavucontrol

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Adc.png)
I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and have selected my Headphones as output devices but sound comes from monitor. I hear nothing with my headphones which worked previously. I have tried using pavucontrol but it is configured the same as settings. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvJYi.png).
How do I get sound through the correct device?

Comment: What type of connection do the headphones use? USB, Bluetooth or 3.5 connector.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You can either turn off HDMI sound, change the HDMI to DisplayPort cable, lower the [priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154586/how-can-i-change-pulseaudio-port-priorities) of HDMI output. The firmware of this product might be faulty, upgrade it or ask the manufacturer. (I can't believe this cost over 200 USD, I would buy a pair of professional studio headphones by SONY.)